# How to know whether files and folder are hidden in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am building simple file manager app but it is showing all file and folder even hidden items also. I couldn't find any library in dart or plugin for this as available in Java or python.

Is there any similar code in dart for Flutter like this
`dir.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)`

I want hidden folder and files to be hidden.

[image]

Comment: add logic to not show the files starting with `.filename` since they are the hidden folders then with a `boolean` you can give the user the option to toggle between hidden files

Answer (score 1):

Android and iOS are both based on unix, and files are considered "hidden" if it starts with a dot. So the check you want would be `boolean isHidden = filename.startsWith(".");`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments

> In Unix-like operating systems, any file or folder that starts with a dot character (for example, `/home/user/.config`), commonly called a **dot file** or **dotfile**, is to be treated as hidden.

Comment: Still there are some folder and files which don not start with "." but they are hidden

Comment: For example? @AlokKumar

Comment: I use [FX File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx), there is a feature to hide or unhide folder or files but it not simply put "." in front of the name, I think it do some changes in property. @ShioT